# Whats up with theese noise materials?

Tags: color

This object consists of 9 cubes with different diffuse colors.
The middle cube has a texture called wood that comes from blender itself.

Why are some colors noisy?

[image: garbled colors]

## edit

Ok, I have now gotten the advice to raise the number of samples. The question then is if there is a way to have a perfect raytrace (no randomness) so that samples as concept would not apply?

Comment: Noicy? :D You mean noisy, right? I guess this render requires more render samples- that's all.

Comment: Can that also be done with only one sample, but without any randomness in the raytracing?

Comment: I found out that picking approximate instead of raytrace and adding some antialiasing produced a really nice result, althought I have no idea what I just did.